# Oracle plsql use value from type in query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have type

**create or replace TYPE days_nt FORCE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10);**

In plsql procedure I have:

```
PROCEDURE test_proc (
      p_header_id   IN   mumber
    , p_days_ids      days_nt
)
AS
Begin

FOR d IN 1..p_days_ids.count LOOP    
     insert into demo(test) values(p_days_ids(d));
    --Here I have eg.  1 and 7
END LOOP;

Select * from my_table where id in ( 1 and 7 from above example);
```

How use value 1 and 7 from p_days_ids in query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use the `MEMBER OF` operator with nested table collection data types (but not with `VARRAY` data types, but that does not apply here);
- You need to `SELECT ... [BULK COLLECT] INTO ... FROM ...` in PL/SQL (or use a cursor); and
- The `INSERT` can be simplified to use `INSERT ... SELECT ...` , which will be more efficient as you only perform a single insert rather than multiple inserts and will handle missing indexes if the array is sparse.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE test_proc (
  p_header_id IN number
, p_days_ids  IN days_nt
)
AS
  TYPE my_table_arr IS TABLE OF my_table%ROWTYPE;
  v_arr my_table_arr;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO demo(test)
  SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(p_days_ids);

  Select *
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_arr
  from   my_table
  where  id MEMBER OF p_days_ids;

  -- Do something with the v_arr collection.
END;
/
```

Then you can call the procedure using:

```
BEGIN
  test_proc(42, days_nt('1', '7'));
END;
/
```

Then you can use:

```sql
Select *
from   demo
where  test in (1, 7);
```

Which outputs:

| TEST |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 7 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/V5HwaJOv)

Comment: Thanks for help,   my_table  also must be declared?

Comment: @user_odoo If you are going to try to `SELECT` from it then, yes, as with any table it has to exist.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understood it.

Type:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE days_nt FORCE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (10);
  2  /

Type created.
```

Sample table (description taken from procedure's `INSERT` statement):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE demo
  2  (
  3     test   VARCHAR2 (10)
  4  );

Table created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc (p_header_id  IN NUMBER,
  2                                         p_days_ids      days_nt)
  3  AS
  4  BEGIN
  5     FOR d IN 1 .. p_days_ids.COUNT
  6     LOOP
  7        INSERT INTO demo (test)
  8             VALUES (p_days_ids (d));
  9     --Here I have eg.  1 and 7
 10     END LOOP;
 11  END;
 12  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing: calling the procedure with 1 and 7 as values:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2     test_proc (1, days_nt (1, 7));
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2    FROM demo
  3   WHERE test IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE (days_nt (1, 7)));

TEST
----------
1
7

SQL>
```